# ASUS X1650 256 MiB - is it sufficient?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, hashpower

Just learned about BitCoin. As I learned now there is no sense using CPU, just GPU. I have ASUS X1650 256 MiB, is it sufficient to ear at list 1-2 BitCoin a week?

Comment: I suspect not - it's getting really hard to make money as a GPU miner, unless you managed to get an AMD card for cheap. Also, the amount of video memory doesn't really matter.

Comment: no, GPU mining going to become obsolete sooner or later. If you have money buy bitcoins from a exchange / trader, otherwise you can preorder / wait for ASIC miners.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, no. I have a 5770 and I get 200MH/s; not really worth it unless you look at it as a hobby and don't want big returns.

Comment: 200Hms - it's how many coins your mine a week?

Comment: @ManInTheHood I suspect that Dominic meant 200 mega hashes per second. To figure out how many bitcoins that is, look [here.](http://www.alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator) Right now, that's about 1 coin a month.

Answer (score 0):

No. That card is WAYYYYYYYY too old. It wasn't good when it was new, and this isn't 2007 anymore. Doesn't have the technical specs required. period. No chance at all to make ANY money. not even 1 cent. Even with a proper video card, i am only making 8 cents a day after power costs (about 1.87 revenue and 1.79 in power costs).

Go here for the profitability calculator. http://www.bitcoinx.com/profit/

And as far as Hash rate (MHash/s) goes, remove 60,000 and put in 1 because 1 is all that card is going to get and that is a long shot.

Comment: Abei, I think your numbers are off. I get 3 MHash/s with my i5 750, and that's a *CPU*.